# There's the possibility to change the axies orientation of a shape/object in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to know if there’s the possibility to move and modify (lines/edges) of a shape not using the axies of the document/artwork but the axies of the shape/edges itself in Adobe Illustrator.

I mean something similar that happens for the 3d object in the 3d environment.

For example, in the image below I would like to move/edit the object using the gray axies. For a regular shape like a square is possible edit using gray axies but isn't the same for others shapes.

[image]

Here an example of how it works with a 3d object.

[image]

Thanks!
Marco

Comment: Sure, its a bit cumbersome, so usually its easier to make a line and slide against that. Mainly because adjusting the direction is hidden under settings and making a tangent line is a 3 click combo that is easily recorded as action at the same time you get opportunities for a very accurate move.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Illustrator has no real 3D structure to speak of. Much of the time trying to mimic what is so basic in a 3D app is overly convoluted and troublesome in Illustrator.

There may be third-party plugins which *might* help, such as the Protractor Panel -- which is part of VectorScribe from AstuteGraphics.com -- or CadTools from HotDoor.com. Whether or not these will assist with your needs, only you can determine. There are free trials available.

Barring plug-ins, this comes down to adjusting the Constrain Angle in the `Preferences` then resetting it. (The Protractor Panel, mentioned previously, simply adds a UI panel for this preference setting, making it more accessible.)

I'd hazard a guess that *most* users merely adapt and learn to move paths carefully -- which can be done easily with the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow). Unfortunately, Illustrator contains no inherent constraining to random angles on the fly.

Comment: alt linetool type select drag delete line

Comment: Yes, that works too... Just pointing out that there *may be* workarounds.. but it's not an inherent thing like in 3D apps.

Comment: i often wondered about the fact that 2D apps deliberately chose to hide the transformations of object hierarchies. Anyway 3D apps need these gizmos to get anything effectively done.

Comment: This, in particular, has always annoyed me about Illustrator. There's no logical reason I can think of as to *why* AI can't merely constrain to an angle.

Comment: it seems to be a paradigm thing since 2D anything seem to have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Modifying, such as selecting two points on one side and dragging it, will definitely change the overall shape because of things such as [one point perspective](https://www.studentartguide.com/articles/one-point-perspective-drawing). However, you can move the overall path with a complicated method.

[image: Setup for a random quadrilateral to be moved at an angle]

Note: This example's coordinates are:
**a** = 379.8108, 349.5676
**b** = 279.8108, 349.5676
**c** = 385.2162, 213.0811
**d** = 306.1622, 273.2162

- Make a line like **f**. The way to do that is `(a - b) / 2 + b` which is the midpoint between **a** and **b**'s x-values. In my example, it would be `(379.8108 - 279.8108) / 2 + 279.8108 = 329.8108`. Make a point with x at 329.8108; y should not matter at that step. If the y coordinates are different, then move the point to where it meets the path and have the x coordinate stay the same as the calculation. Do the same for **c** and **d**. Once the two points are made, those should be connected so it becomes a line or a path. Without "Snap to Grid" or "Snap to Pixel", the path will still recognize you trying to lengthen **f**.
- Make a line like **e**, having the y value of where you'd like the lowest y coordinate value point to be.
- Select both the path and **f**.
- Use the "option" or "alt" key to select **f**. This will make it so the focus will go more towards **f**.
- Drag both towards **e** while keeping **f** stay at the same Δx, Δy coordinates (meaning **f** will also be dragged, but you can view and also have a "Snap to Point" function in it, though it's not a requirement).
- Once **c** or the lowest y coordinate value point on the path, makes it to **e**, you have completed a transition.

It would end up looking like this:
[image: Final placement of path]

Besides this, there seem to not be many solutions; Others may contain even more extra steps or additional paths, lines, calculations, etc.